# How should I implement my own version of curry in Racket?

Tags: racket

My version should behave identically to curry, but need only work on procedures with fixed arity. Where should I begin in order to create my own version of curry?

```
> ((my-curry even?) 2)

#t    
> (((my-curry cons) 1) 2)

'(1 . 2)
> ((my-curry cons 1) 2)

'(1 . 2)
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to find the ariry of a procedure?

Comment: The marked duplicate is a poor one; all the answers assume you know the arity of the curried function ahead of time which isn't the case here, and they didn't act like Racket's `curry` function in other respects either. Plus they're standard scheme, not Racket.